# PDF*.tmp file are not deleted and Out of Memory Exception when CacheToDisk is used

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, out-of-memory, activereports

We are using ActiveReports in our project, in the code we are using CacheToDisk property to avoid memory exception. We used WCF service, which will call a method in dll which contains the ActiveReport Report generation. The WCF service is hosted in Windows Service.

When reports are exported to PDF, in IsolatedStorage folder the PDF*.tmp files are created and it is not deleted automatically. We used Dispose() method of the Document object, the AR*.tmp files are removed but PDF*.tmp files (each file around 100 MB) are not removed. We hard coded the IsolatedStorage folder and gave full permission to the user, under which Windows Service is running.

Please let us know how to delete the PDF*.tmp files automatically in IsolatedStorage folder ? Also some times we get out of memory exception for some reports  even after using CacheToDisk (exporting to excel or pdf)  and some times the Windows Service itself stopped automatically due to memory exception.

Answer (score 1):

Varun

We have been working on getting your issue resolved through your post here at: http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/145096/ShowPost.aspx
Please follow up on the post on this forum to see if the related issue is resolved or not.

I will update this post once we have a final resolution.

Thanks

raji